# Ascensor controls created programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ascensor

I am using the [Ascensor](http://kirkas.ch/ascensor/) Framework

I am wondering if its possible to create next and previous buttons programatically rather than through using the class of the specific element you want to scroll to?

I can see from the the .js file that there are functions created for this process `next()` for example.

However when I try to use this function in my own script file called after this framework is loaded in, it is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that might be interested, I delved into the framework and found the following -

```
$("element").on("click", function() {
     next();
});
```

Just change the element to the class/id of your own element